# Absolute Integrable Sinc function

Tags: stability

How do we prove that $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg|\dfrac{\sin t}{\pi t}\bigg|dt\to \infty$$
This comes in the context of stability of LTI system with impulse response $h(t) = \dfrac{\sin t}{\pi t}$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This feels like homework; even if it isn't, please discuss the approach you've got so far!

Comment: Hint: Try to find an upper bound the function you are integrating and show that the integral of that upper bound diverges.

Comment: @AtulIngle that'd be necessary, but not sufficient! But I think I know what you're going for.

Comment: oh I should've said lower bound! not upper bound.

Comment: @AtulIngle Since the sin function has value $0$ at periodically spaced points along the axis, any lower bond on the integrand must also have value $0$ at these points. Did you have any specific function in mind?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25591/36936

Comment: probably means $$h(t) = \dfrac{\sin(\pi t)}{\pi t}$$ otherwise i think the $\pi$ in the denominator is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

The question has an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25591/36936) on Math SE. The argument goes as follows:

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left| \frac{\sin t}{\pi t} \right|dt &=& \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} \left| \frac{\sin t}{t} \right| dt \\
&>& \frac{1}{\pi} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{|n+1|\pi}\int_{n\pi}^{(n+1)\pi} |\sin t|dt \\
&=& \frac{2}{\pi^2} \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{|n|}\\
&\rightarrow& \infty
\end{eqnarray}
where in each interval $[n\pi, (n+1)\pi]$ we lower bound $1/t$ with $1/(n+1) \pi$.

Comment: nice and elegant :)

Comment: yes, and I take no credit for it. Please upvote the linked Math.SE answer!

Comment: An honest, good idea. Did that!